# enable / disable edittext using radio button in android

Tags: android

I am new in android. I have two radio buttons and edit text.to check the radio button, it disable the edit text and prevent input pad from appearing and to check the radio button2 enable edit text...  I tried a lot of answer but nothing works.
this is my code

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton radioButton, radioButton2;
    EditText editText;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        radioButton.setChecked(true);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        if ((radioButton.isChecked())) {
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        } 
        else {
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A CheckBox is better suited for an on/off switch. A couple of RadioButtons is better suited for a gender selection (as a typical example).

Comment: I agree with Rotwang. Just use a simple checkbox, you can get rid of the radio-buttons. Hence, the java code and xml code will also be much more simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Hey first put the two radio button in a Radio group.

Check this code.

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            switch(checkedId)
            {
            case R.id.radio0:
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                 editText.setEnabled(false);
                 editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this help.Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use method of setOnCheckedChangeListener and manage checked and uncheck event.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this piece of your code:

```
if ((radioButton.isChecked())) {
    editText.setEnabled(false);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
} else {
    editText.setEnabled(false);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}
```

and put replace it by:

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        } else {
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }  
    }
});
```

This solution will be better if you use `CheckBox` instead of `RadioButton` since your need is more compatible with `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        switch(checkedId)
        {
            case R.id.radio0:
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```